# Is it possible to modify the terminal's previously printed and buffered characters?

Tags: c++, terminal

I will start by saying: I am already aware that I can use '\b' and ansi escape codes to get the cursor position, move the cursor, and get the terminal size.

However, once the-text-I-am-interested-in has scrolled past the terminal's view, it seems impossible to modify said text.

For instance, imagine that the terminal has the following displayed on it:

```
first line [...]
a
b
c
...
last line
```

And when printing a new line, let's imagine that "first line [...]" scrolls out of screen, disappearing above "a":

```
a
b
c
...
last line
inserted line
```

Would it still be possible to modify the line ('first line [...]'), perhaps using the terminal's own buffer, in C++?

The idea would be to modify the line, such that if you do scroll back up, you would see the modified version (bonus points if you can also still print ansi codes for formatting out-of-screen).

Comment: Not in standard C++, but most platforms have some kind of console API, so you should look to that for what you are looking for.

Comment: This will depend on the capabilities of the terminal.

Comment: Sounds like you're using a terminal / console provided by the OS.  Any solution, even if it's possible, is going to depend on the way that particular console is implemented, and won't be at all portable. If you're restricting yourself to one OS,                                                              there may be a way to do it.

Comment: I understand these comments, however some solutions, such as ansi escape codes, work on a majority of terminals. Is there no such similar feature for this purpose? For example, I have just managed to make this work on windowed cmd, however, the same program does not run properly in vscode's integrated version of cmd.

Comment: The general solution is to use [the ncurses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) as it's been ported to a wide variety of systems.

Comment: C++ IO is doomed to support a very low-level abstraction because of the exceptionably broad umbrella of supported systems, many of which don't have anything you'd recognize as a terminal and are simply dumping bits onto a wire.

Comment: Search the internet for "ANSI terminal escape sequences".  Hopefully your terminal will accept them.

Comment: Maybe a better solution is to change your program to a Windowing (GUI) application.  There's more freedom with a graphics window than with a terminal or console window.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Did you read the question/comments? I already know about them. However, the only ansi escape codes I could find relating to scrolling do not scroll, and instead move the viewport down and create empty lines at the top. But, if you do know of any ansi escape codes that fulfill the purpose described here, please, do make an answer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Making a windowed GUI terminal is beyond the scope of the question, and while I do intend to do that someday, there are severe drawbacks to doing so (opengl configuration, portability, etc etc...). Therefore, it is not a proper answer to this question.

Comment: @user4581301 I was attempting not to use ncurses due to its very strange API and poor documentation. I also do not know for sure it will support the feature described above, thus making an attempt at using it a risky time investment.

Comment: `ncurses` is the most used library for what you want to do.

Comment: @ZeroZ30o:  If you realize, I am adding comments, not answering your question.  The GUI is a suggestion and not a direct answer to your question.  I've been programming terminals since the days of the Teletype and Line Printers.  I know from experience that not all terminals have cursors or can position cursors.  Some terminals can do fields and erase them (these are those old data entry or form terminals, where "ENTER" meant to submit the information on the screen).  I haven't memorized the ANSI terminal sequences, thus I recommend you to read up on them.

Comment: *'I was attempting not to use ncurses...'* -- Having a quick search and you should be able to find some modern alternatives TUI libraries, like [NotCurses](https://github.com/dankamongmen/notcurses) and [FTXUI](https://github.com/ArthurSonzogni/FTXUI)

Comment: Like pretty much everything else, [GNU has a library for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline), and it may be a better fit for your usecase.

Comment: This might also be a good time for the OP to explain why they need this, as it's beginning to sound like XY Problem. Modifying stuff in the scroll buffer of a terminal is unusual. You can probably implement your _own_ scrollable area with ncurses, thus somewhat liberating yourself from terminal abuse. On the topic of graphical/windowed approach, OpenGL is not relevant here. Something like Qt is more portable, if portability is the main concern. Unclear what the real goal is, and what the main design requirements actually are.

Comment: You can't rely on a terminal storing all the text in memory.  In general, you are positioning the terminal's cursor and overwriting text.

Comment: In the old days, we would issue a Form Feed character, then redraw screen; the host computer would perform this.  The terminal only "arranged" the screen according to the {control} characters sent to it.